# Symfony PhpUnit to mock PHP built-in method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, symfony4, prophecy

I am using **`prophesize`** method to mock Class

Example:

```
$user = $this->prophesize(User::class);
```

How to mock PHP built-in method?

exactly I need to mock `locale_accept_from_http($language);`

Do you have idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mock PHPs native method, but instead write a wrapper for everything you need.

```
class LocaleListener
{
    protected $language;

    public function __construct($language) {
        $this->language = $language;
    }

    public function getPreferredLocale() {
        return locale_accept_from_http($this->language);
    }
}
```

And now you can mock that with:

```
$listener = $this->prophesize(LocaleListener::class);
$listener->getPreferredLocale()->willReturn('en_GB');
```

Any if your are interested in the way Symfony proposes to handle the users locale from the header, check out this EventListener in their demo app:
https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/src/EventSubscriber/RedirectToPreferredLocaleSubscriber.php